# Can I change a parameter name in a C# WebMethod?

Tags: .net, parameters, asmx, webmethod

Is it possible for a C# WebMethod to accept a different parameter name than its client sends?

For example, given a client sending this message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetStatus xmlns="http://example.com/">
            <Arg1>5</Arg1>
            <Arg2>3</Arg2>
        </GetStatus>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can the existing WebMethod be rewritten to accommodate different argument names? Something like this?

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetStatus(
    [MessageParameter(Name = "Arg1")] string orderId, 
    [MessageParameter(Name = "Arg2")] string typeId)
```

Comment: FYI, ASMX is a legacy technology which should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to do it with the XmlElementAttribute, e.g:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetStatus(
[XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "Arg1")] string orderId, 
[XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "Arg2")] string typeId)
```

Comment: You've just saved me a lot or arse ache, thanks dude. I'm stuck having to work with a badly implemented asmx SOAP webservice that has inconsistent parameter casing which I don't want to propagate through my application. This allows me to transform the casing on the door and then deal with sensible casing from thereon in. This post should be marked as the answer.

Comment: using System.Xml.Serialization;