# C# WebMethod - Change parameter name for List of strings

Tags: c#, soap, asmx, webmethod

I need change the parameters name in a web method to be as follow:

```
<soap:Envelope ...>
<soap:Body>
    <Company>
        <CompanyId>AA</CompanyId>
        <CompanyId>BB</CompanyId>
        <CompanyId>CC</CompanyId>
        <CompanyId>DD</CompanyId>
    </Conmpany>
</soap:Body>
```

I found this post: [Can I change a parameter name in a C# WebMethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997838/can-i-change-a-parameter-name-in-a-c-sharp-webmethod) However, this works only specifying the number of parameters. In my case I need it to be a list of strings so the user can provide 1 of many paramters in the request.

By just doing 'List < String> Company' as parameter I get:

```
<Company>
    <string>AA</string>
    <string>BB</string>
    <string>CC</string>
    <string>DD</string>
</Conmpany>
```

But using XmlElementAttribute doesn't work when trying to change the 'string' display. Any advise?

Comment: Have you looked at XmlArrayItemAttribute?

Comment: create method taking string[] as parameter, pass you company as new[] {"AA", "BB", ..."ZZ"}